# Get advert links or get adverts links?

Tags: grammar

What if the best variant to use: get **advert** links or get **adverts** links? The idea is that there are a lot of adverts and each has a link. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean *get adverts" links* with a possessive plural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an "advert link" would be taken by most people to mean a link to an advert, then "advert links" would be multiple links leading to an advert. While this could be interpreted as multiple links to the same advert, I'd guess that most people would read "advert links" as being multiple links each to one or more adverts. The risk with "adverts links" is that people think that you've missed an apostrophe and that it should be "advert's links".

If you want to avoid ambiguity, you could try "get links to adverts", it's only one word longer and clearly conveys that there are multiple links and multiple adverts.

Comment: "Adverts links" has a bigger risk: for most speakers, it's ungrammatical, because it has a plural as a noun modifier.

Answer (score 1):

In *advert links*, *advert* is a noun modifier. This construct **doesn't mark number**: the noun modifier is morphologically singular, even when it's semantically plural.

So even though the links are to multiple adverts, it's *advert links*, not **adverts links*. Similarly, oil from olives is *olive oil*, not **olives oil*, and a basket of eggs is an *egg basket*. Even pluralia tanta lose their plural marking when they're noun modifiers: a press for trousers is a *trouser press*, even for speakers who would never say *a trouser*.

(There are some cases where a noun modifier can be morphologically plural: for example, a hospital can have a *burns ward*, or a school can have an *activities center*. These are probably because the plurals have been reinterpreted as different lexical items from the singulars, so they can't used without number marking, but linguists are still arguing about this.)

Comment: Or like how with *cattle prods*, you cannot make *cattle* singular.